DDR3 Termination Resistors Messing Up SI?
Do these results make any sense? Or is there perhaps a bug in the Altium Designer Keysight SI plug-in?
I'm testing the new Altium SI plug-in by Keysight. In particular, I'm curious about using it to test the impact of termination resistors on the DDR3 lines. The plugin has a bug that's keeping it from running our on AD project, so while Altium's tech support is looking into that, I'm testing it on an identical stack-up in a simple PCB project. It's literally just running from one header on the top side of the board to another on the bottom side of the board.
Here is the simple PCB layout without the termination resistor. No top copper pour, just a curved 50 Ω trace routed from one pad to another with teardrops and ground stitching vias.





The insertion and return losses are about what I'd expect for the fundamental frequency and the third harmonic on basic FR4.
BUT now check this out. All you have to do is add the termination resistor in, and it screws everything up. Note that the header pads themselves are only about 1500 mil apart.




See how the presence of the termination resistor results in some massive degradation to insertion and return loss? It doesn't make sense to me. While the values might still be arguably acceptable for DDR3, I don't understand how a simple pull-up affects the signal this way. And the results are the same no matter where you position that resistor.
Do these results make any sense? Or is there perhaps a bug in the plug-in?

What are the boundary conditions? -- Are the header pad capacitances being accounted for? What are the headers modeled as (e.g. IBIS something)?

@TimWilliams No idea. The plug-in doesn't give me options to configure those. Assuming it's pulling from the SI models specified in the schematics, they're generic header and resistor models that Altium uses in all simulations, which should specify the pads are all generic passive.

@wisner Can you do a high impedance resistor or one that is double your impedance of the line and see if the results change?

@VoltageSpike The original was 50 Ω to match the transmission line. I swapped it for a 1 MΩ, and I get the exact same results :/
